# Brownie import file that has imports with '@...'

Tags: python, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, brownie

I have this contract:

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.0;
import "Uniswap/v3-core@1.0.0/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV3Pool.sol";
import "Uniswap/v3-periphery@1.3.0/contracts/interfaces/ISwapRouter.sol";

contract Test {

}
```

and this brownie-config.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  - Uniswap/v3-core@1.0.0
  - Uniswap/v3-periphery@1.3.0
```

using *brownie compile* throws the following:

```
ParserError: Source "@uniswap/v3-core/contracts/interfaces/callback/IUniswapV3SwapCallback.sol" not found: File outside of allowed directories.
 --> C:/Users/username/.brownie/packages/Uniswap/v3-periphery@1.3.0/contracts/interfaces/ISwapRouter.sol:5:1:
  |
5 | import '@uniswap/v3-core/contracts/interfaces/callback/IUniswapV3SwapCallback.sol';
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Makes sense to me that this import can't be resolved, but is there anyway to fix this without modifying the Uniswap source code?

Edit: to clarify, this is what the beginning of *ISwapRouter.sol* looks like:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0-or-later
pragma solidity >=0.7.5;
pragma abicoder v2;

import '@uniswap/v3-core/contracts/interfaces/callback/IUniswapV3SwapCallback.sol';
```

the import of '@uniswap/..." is what is causing the problem

Answer (score 1):

in brownie-config.yaml file

add remappings

```
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings: 
      # put the correct version
      - "@uniswap/lib=uniswap/uniswap-lib@1.1.2"
      - "@uniswap/v2-core=uniswap/uniswap-v2-core@1.0.1"
```

Comment: thats not it unfortunately, the brownie-config was in root already. I edited the question to clarify the problem

Comment: share brownie-yaml config please

Comment: it's in the question text

Comment: Your brownie config should have deoendencies for your project. I m on phone right now cannot view correct version so find the correct versioons